# Consolidating 5 table into one

Tags: sql, sql-insert

So I have 5 tables which need to go into Result; 2-digit, 3-digit, 4-digit, 5-digit, and 6-digit. They are of the same structure. Would the following code accomplish the task:

```
 Insert into Result select * from 2-digit, 3-digit, 4-digit, 5-digit, 6-digit;
```

Or does it need to look like this

```
Insert into Result select * from 2-digit, select * from 3-digit, select * from 4-digit,select * from 5-digit,select * from 6-digit;
```

Below is some sample data. The desired result is to simply consolidate these three tables into one with no manipulation of the data or rows. the end result should have 12 rows.

```
2 digit
x     job code    employment
32    10    4569
32    11    4521

3 digit
x     job code    employment
32    101    1203
32    102    3366
32    111    1000
32    112    3521

4 digit
32    1011   1203
32    1025   1000
32    1028   2366
32    1111   500
32    1112   500
32    1123   2899
32    1124   45
32    1125   577
```

Comment: is 102100 a column value?

Comment: 102100 is just an example of a column value that appears numerous times throughout. I compile 24 fixed width files into 5 tables based on the length of the job code. The original data always begins with 6 digits and then is truncated to 2,3,4, or 5 digits.

Comment: 2-digit, 3-digit, 4-digit, 5-digit, 6-digit are to be inserted in different tables?

Comment: 2-digit, 3-digit, 4-digit, 5-digit, 6-digit are to be "consolidated" into Result. I saw an answer about how to do so with 2 tables and it used a code like what I mention above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with `SELECT . . . UNION`:

```
 SELECT * FROM table1
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT * FROM table2
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM table3
 . . . and so on
```

If the table structures are not *exactly the same* (they have a different number of columns or the columns have slightly different names, or are in a different order) then you will have to replace `*` with the column names explicitly listed.

Having the five tables in the first place is a flaw in the database design -- why not keep them all in one table and then just `SELECT` out the rows you want.

Comment: It is complex but in short, the data comes in flawed form and nothing can be done about it. All come with extra characters and then I use the substring command to delineate 2,3,4,5, and 6 digit codes.

Answer (score 0):

use SUBSTRING()

```
 INSERT INTO Results
 SELECT SUBSTRING('102100',1,2) [2-digits],
        SUBSTRING('102100',1,3) [3-digits],
        SUBSTRING('102100',1,4) [4-digits],
        SUBSTRING('102100',1,5) [5-digits],
        '102100' [6-digits]
   FROM tablename
```

Result

```
2-digits    3-digits    4-digits    5-digits    6-digits
10          102         1021        10210       102100
```

substitute '102100' with the column name you have from your table

Comment: If I was to compile all 24 fixed with files into one, I would have 25 to 30 mentions of 102100 and no clear indication as to which ones to truncate to 2 or 3. I already do the commands listed above at the end of each subunit. At the end of 4 digit, i use a substring command like what is listed above. 

What I want to know is how to consolidate the entirety of the 2-digit and so on into one with removing no rows.

Comment: "What I want to know is how to consolidate the entirety of the 2-digit and so on into one with removing no rows." - I don't get what your goal is. Please give sample data and expected result instead.

Comment: Look in the body of the question now